# winsorize does not affect the outlier

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I have this set of data in a DataFrame :

|  | data | winsor_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1660 | 1660 |
| 1 | 600 | 600 |
| 2 | 50 | 50 |
| 3 | 3173.55 | 3173.55 |
| 4 | 30 | 30 |
| 5 | 120 | 120 |
| 6 | 7.84 | 7.84 |
| 7 | 1660 | 1660 |
| 8 | 33.3 | 33.3 |
| 9 | 2069.49 | 2069.49 |
| 10 | 42 | 42 |
| 11 | 384.29 | 384.29 |
| 12 | 1660 | 1660 |
| 13 | 1338.57 | 1338.57 |
| 14 | 200000 | 200000 |
| 15 | 1760 | 1760 |

The 14th value is clearly an outlier.

```
    from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

    dfdailyIncome['winsor_data'] = winsorize(df['data'], limits=(0,0.95))
```

I do not understand why the outlier is not clipped. May be it has something to do with the way the quantiles are calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the 'limits' parameter.
If you want to cut 10 percent of your largest values, you need:

```
dfdailyIncome['winsor_data'] = winsorize(df['data'], limits=[0,0.1])
```

You cut 95 percent of your largest data in your example.

Hint: Even if you would use `winsorize(df['data'], limits=[0,0.05])`, your data would stay the same because 5 percent of your largest data is the original data because you have less than 20 values.

See the example from here for further explanation: [scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html)

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right. it's 0.1. Regarding the 20 values, the 0.95 percentile is 52k when it is computed using the linear interpolation method. Why the winsorize method does not clip to that value ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I guess the method only allows values that are in the original array. It seems like there is no way to influence that so I assume this procedure is normal behaviour for the winsorize method.